# convergence of sum of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that if $a_n \neq 0$ for every $n$, then

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1- \frac{\sin(a_n)}{a_n}\right)$$

converges if and only if

$$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2}$$

converges?

Comment: Source? Motivation? Failed approaches?

Comment: Reading some calculus on my spare time, and found this "sentence" and tried proving it unsuccessfully.

Motivation: Fun.

Didn't manage to really start so no failed approaches.
I only know that a_n goes to zero no matter which side we start from.

Comment: Then, (1) would you know how to prove that $a_n\to0$? And (2) assuming $a_n\to0$, would you be able to compare $1-\frac{\sin a_n}{a_n}$ with multiples of $a_n^2$?

Comment: (1) yes.
(2), no.. please help

Comment: Are you familiar with the Maclaurin series for $\sin x$?

Comment: @Brian: Just saw your comment after I posted my hint.  If you want me to remove my hint, please let me know...

Comment: First prove that $a_n\to 0$.  Then show that for sufficiently small $a$, there are values $C,D$ such that $Ca^2\leq 1-\frac{\sin a}a\leq Da^2$.

Comment: Use the Taylor series for $\sin$: $$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} + ...$$

Comment: @JavaMan: By all means leave it up.

Comment: Guy: *(1) yes. (2) no...* Then I suggest you append a proof of (1) at the end of your post, so that we can start from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\begin{align}
\sin(x) = &x - \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + \frac{1}{5!}x^5 + \dots.
\\
&\Downarrow
\\
\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = &1 - \frac{1}{3!}x^2 + \frac{1}{5!}x^4 + \dots
\\
&\Downarrow
\\
1 - \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = &\frac{1}{3!}x^2 - \frac{1}{5!}x^4 + \dots
\end{align}$$

So for small $x$, we have $1 - \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = cx^2 + o(x^4)$.  Let $x = a_n$, and note that $a_n \to 0$, necessarily.